# deleting a node using a method in Java

Tags: java, oop, nodes, peek

I've figured out the `add()` and `print()` methods.  Now I want to make my `delete()` and `peek()` methods work.  I can't figure out the issue with my code having tried many times over and over again.

NodeFN class:

```
public class NodeFN {
    private String data; // Data for node.
    private NodeFN next; // Next node.

public NodeFN(String data) {
    this.data = data; // Take the data value passed in & store it in the data field.
    this.next = null; // Take the next node & store it in the next field.
}

// Mutator functions.
   public String getData() {return data;}
   public NodeFN getNext() {return next;}
   public void setData(String d) {data = d;}
   public void setNext(NodeFN n) {next = n;}
}
```

Queue class:

```
public class Queue {
    NodeFN head = null; // Head of node.
    public String n; // Will be used later.

public Queue(String n) { 
    head = new NodeFN(n); // head is now an object of NodeFN which holds a string.
}

public void add(String n) {
    NodeFN nn = new NodeFN(n); // nn is now an object of NodeFN class which holds a string.
    if(head == null) { // If head is null.
        head = nn; // Make head equal to the first node.
    }

    if(nn.getData().compareTo(head.getData()) < 0) {
        nn.setNext(head); // Puts nn in the beginning in the list.
        head = nn; // Makes sure nn is in the beginning of the list.
    }
}

public void delete() {
    NodeFN nn = new NodeFN(n);

    while(head.getNext() != null) {
        head = head.getNext(); 
    }   
    head = nn;
}

public void peek() {
    NodeFN nn = new NodeFN(n);

    while(nn.getData().compareTo(head.getData()) > 0) {
        System.out.println(head.getData() + " ");
        head = head.getNext();
    }
}

public void print() {
    if(head == null) { // If head is empty.
        System.out.println(); // Print nothing.
    }

    while(head != null) { // While head is filled with data
        // Print the data so long as the add() method has a valid string parameter.
        System.out.println(head.getData() + " "); 
        head = head.getNext(); // head will get to the next node and print.
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Queue q = new Queue("test1");
    q.add("test2");
    q.add("test3");
    q.add("test4");
    q.peek();
   } 
}
```

Comment: Why does your `delete` not take any arguments? Should it not take a `String` and then delete a node that has that string as the data?

Comment: Isn't there a way to do it without having it take a `String`?  I'm pretty sure there is.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the peek should only return a copy the current queue head and doesn't do any changes on the current queue.

```
public void peek() {
       NodeFN nn = new NodeFN(n);

       while(nn.getData().compareTo(head.getData()) > 0) {
            System.out.println(head.getData() + " ");
            head = head.getNext();
       }
}
```